# Easy way to combine multiple CSS files into one?

Tags: css

I have multiple different skins for a site and am expecting to do additional skinning soon. It's set up very verbosely currently like so:

> /theme1/myCss.css
>
> /theme2/myCss.css
>
> /theme3/myCss.css
>
> /theme4/myCss.css
>
> ....

I am wanting to move everything that each theme has in common into a general css file that each theme can then use

> /common/myCommonCss.css

Is there a tool that can compare the CSS declaration in each file, determine if they are identical, and then flag them (or ideally cut/copy them) into another file?

Answer (score 1):

tools such Kdiff, Notepad++, beyond compare would work for you.

Comment: Yeah, I was considering one of these or winmerge, but a lot of the CSS files aren't even consistent on where they put certain tags making it impossible to see differences/similarities. I may just end up writing my own regex tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine CSS files without knowing HTML markup. For example these two selectors are same in first glance:

```
.class1 .class2{color:red;}
.class1 > .class2{color:red;}
```

But these are acting different for different HTML markup. So you need a tool that knows your html.

If you are using php then [this tool](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) is useful.